# System.IO.FileSystemWatcher does not watch file changed by Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I just upgraded Visual Studio to version 2013 Ultimate, I found `System.IO.FileSystemWatcher` class failed to watch file edited by Visual Studio 2013. suppose I have below code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\test", "*.txt");
        watcher.Changed += watcher_Changed;
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        Console.Read();
        watcher.Changed -= watcher_Changed;
    }

    static void watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("file is changed");
    }
}
```

If I edit file `C:\test\a.txt` with notepad, the program will report the file is change, but if I edit it with Visual Studio 2013, my program keep silent. Why?

Comment: Think there is a known limitation .net Method `FileStream.Flush` method, please read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2011/03/23/filesystemwatcher-class-does-not-fire-change-events-when-notifyfilters-size-is-used.aspx) article.

Comment: I just tried this with VS2013 RC and it works fine.

Comment: My VS2013 is a release version it is strange it does not work. However, thanks @adrianbanks information, once I add code watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.LastAccess; it works. thank you all

Comment: I had o add NotifyFilters.Security for it to work. VS is running as administrator and UAC is disabled.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I noticed that when editing files in Visual Studio 2013, it created temporary files then deletes the original file and renames the temporary file to the same name. So to catch normal edits handle the `System.IO.FileSystemWatcher`'s `Changed` event, and for edits in Visual Studio, handle the `Renamed` event.

Answer (score 7):

I've checked solutions of Marcus and Shuping but in my case they didn't work.
The thing I did to solve the problem was to set:

```
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.CreationTime;
```

After that `Changed` event started to work.

VS 2013 version: `12.0.30501.00 Update 2`

Comment: No idea why doesn't have more votes.  I've seen so many answers explaining atomic saves and how this is 'by design' and how you can listen for other events like Rename and Create but this is exactly what I wanted.